# Receiving None from function that is explicitly returning False

Tags: python

I have a function that iterates through tests and executes them.  Before executing each test, it calls a function `confirm_execute()` to check if the tests have been cancelled.  `confirm_execute()` is shown below (pardon the mess of debugging messages):

```
def confirm_execute(self):
    self._update_hil_status()
    status = self.hil_status['status']
    print 'STATUS =', status

    if status == 'TESTING':
        return True
    elif status == 'CANCEL':
        print '##### Cancelling #####'
        return False

    elif status == 'REQUEST_STOP':
        print '##### Stopping tests #####'
        self._set_hil_status(status='STOPPED')
    elif status == 'STOPPED':
        time.sleep(5)
    elif status == 'RESUME':
        print '##### Resuming tests #####'
        self._set_hil_status(status='TESTING')
    else:
        print '##### Invalid status {} - setting stop status #####'.format(status)
        self._set_hil_status(status='STOPPED')

    self.confirm_execute()  # only exit if status is testing or cancel
```

The portion of function that checks for permission before executing a test is here:

```
allow = self.status.confirm_execute()
if allow:
    print 'continue: {}'.format(allow)
    # run a test
else:
    print 'cancel: {}'.format(allow)
    # clean up
```

Here's the issue: when I set the `status` to `CANCEL`, `confirm_execute` seems to return `None` instead of `False`.  Here's the output on the console when I stop a set of tests and then attempt to cancel:

```
STATUS = REQUEST_STOP
##### Stopping tests #####
SETTING STOPPED
STATUS = STOPPED
STATUS = STOPPED
STATUS = CANCEL
##### Cancelling #####
cancel: None
```

Note that I get the `##### Cancelling #####` message, which means that I should be returning `False`.  However, the value of `allow` received seems to be `None`.

What simple mistake am I making?

Comment: You probably mean `return self.confirm_execute()` when you recursively re-call the method. Otherwise you are abandoning the return value of the recursive call and falling off the end of the method (which means returning `None`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is not the appropriate solution here. Every time the result is not CANCEL or TESTING, the function will call itself; but you do not return the values from those nested calls, so they are lost.

Instead of recursing, you should put the whole function within a `while True` loop - so it will continue to loop until one of the return cases is reached.

Comment: Recursion could work here if it's not more than a few hundred calls deep. Else it will blow the stack (hence the site name). Unfortunately, Python does not feature tail call elimination.

Comment: @9000 technically it would - but why risk it/do it if it's not required anyway? :p

Comment: @JonClements: No point risking it. The point is that the thing could work for smaller test cases, and then suddenly blow up under production load. Something to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Your function only explicitly return a value for `TESTING` and `CANCEL`.
Otherwise it just prints things, calls itself, and does not explicitly return anything. This means it implicitly returns `None`.

What you wanted is `return self.confirm_execute()`.

Comment: I get it - the recursively called function is returning False, but the initial returns None.